# Magento delete credit card numbers

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Currently I am using SQL from phpMyAdmin to delete credit card numbers from Magento tables with commands like

> UPDATE `mg3u_sales_flat_order_payment` SET cc_number_enc=NULL

I would like a PHP script I can execute instead of logging into phpMyAdmin all the time. I have tried to write the code but am not sure if it will work.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

 require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app();

 $prefix=(string)Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix(); // Get Prefix

 // fetch write database connection that is used in Mage_Core module
 $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

 foreach ...  

 $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

 $write->query("update " . $prefix . "sales_flat_quote_payment set cc_number_enc=null"); // Update Quote
 $write->query("update " . $prefix . "sales_flat_order_payment set cc_number_enc=null"); // Update Order

 }
 echo "complete";
```

Comment: I hope you're doing this to get back your PCI compliance because that's super bad to have in your database.

Comment: @tadman it's OOB functionality with Magento